# VueJS show splash screen after login (different landing page)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have my `VueJS` application in which the user logins and depending on the role a specific landing page is pushed in the router.

Here the sample code or the store that handles login:

```
login({ dispatch, commit, state }, data) {
    return API.post('api/account/login', data).then(({ data }) => {
      if (data.success) {
        var view = getView(data.data, state)
        router.push(view);        
      }
      return Promise.resolve(data);
    });
  },
```

So as you can see I can have different landing pages after login depending on user role. What I need to do is that no matter what landing page is I have to show a Splash screen (modal) after the user logins.

If its only one landing page for all I guess I could add something in the mount event of that view to show the modal, but because I have 9 different landing views I dont think the best way is to add the same code to the 9 views.

Is there a way I can do that in a propper or best practice way?

Thanks

Comment: How about putting to your Splash screen into a separate component with its own route? And then let the Splash component handle the routing to your view with the use of a `prop` in a timeout.
Another way could be mounting a new Vue instance right before routing to your view that you place over your app and destroy in a few seconds. Your view will already have been loaded in the background and will be visible as soon as you destroy the instance.

Comment: Second option could maybe work, anyway i dont have clue on how to do that. For second option the landing view will be shown first and then modal will come up?

Comment: Is there no way like to inherit this landing pages from a parent view that has this functionality?

Comment: You can nest all your landing pages inside of a parent route. The component of the parent should contain another router-view for its children. That way you wrap your landing page view inside of its parent view

Answer (score 0):

As a followup on my comment: you can mount a separate Vue instance. You can do it with something like this:

```js
createNewInstance: function(){
    const splash = new Vue({
    methods: {
      closeHandler() {
        return function() {
          splash.$destroy();
          splash.$el.remove();
        };
      }
    },
    render(h) {
      return h(YourSplashComponent, {
        mounted() {
          setTimeout(this.closeHandler(), 3000)
        }
      });
    }
  }).$mount();
  document.body.appendChild(splash.$el);
}
```

Just be sure to import and create a component on where `YourSplashComponent` is stated in the example.
Call the function right before you do trigger your route

Comment: Is it ok to call this function in the Store where i have the login function then?

Comment: Technically you could, but its not best practice. But i see you also call your routes from the store so you might as well do it. However if you want to write it properly its best to leave these actions in your Vue component and outside of the store

Answer (score 0):

If you have 9 different routes a user can be directed to, could you:

- create a modal component
- load it into these views/routes
- open it when the route is mounted

This way the modal code is centralized in its own component, and can watch for a property change to appear.